# Unable to connect to Pokertracker postgreSQL database

Tags: database, postgresql, connection, postgresql-9.3

I am following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_data_access/python_postgresql_database_connection.htm) to connect to a PostgreSQL database stored on my computer.
I am using Windows 10 and I have installed PostgreSQL 9.3

I run the following code:

```
import psycopg2
class PostgreSQL():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conecta()
    def conecta(self):
        #establishing the connection
        conn = psycopg2.connect(
        database="PokerTracker 4 Database", user='postgres', password='dbpass', host='localhost', port= '5432')
        #Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        #Executing an MYSQL function using the execute() method
        cursor.execute("select version()")
        # Fetch a single row using fetchone() method.
        data = cursor.fetchone()
        print("Connection established to: ",data)
        conn.close()
if __name__=='__main__':
    PostgreSQL()
```

I receive the following error from the cmd while running the script:

```
C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\OMAHA>python postgresql.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\OMAHA\postgresql.py", line 18, in <module>
    PostgreSQL()
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\OMAHA\postgresql.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.conecta()
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\Desktop\OMAHA\postgresql.py", line 7, in conecta
    conn = psycopg2.connect(
  File "C:\Users\USUARIO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError
```

What am I doing wrong? I copied the code from the tutorial.

Comment: Can you connect via psql?

Comment: Hi, it is solved. The database name is PT4DB and not PokerTracker 4 Database

Answer (score 0):

If someone is trying to connect to Pokertracker database, the error was the database name was uncorrect. Go on pokertracker to File->Open User Data Folder. Open config folder, open pokertracker.cfg and there you have all the info.

In my case this are the parameters:

```
import psycopg2
class PostgreSQL():
    def __init__(self):
        self.conecta()
    def conecta(self):
        hostname = 'localhost'
        username = 'postgres'
        password = 'dbpass'
        database = 'PT4DB'
        myConnection = psycopg2.connect( host=hostname, user=username, password=password, dbname=database )
        cursor = myConnection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("""SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
           WHERE table_schema = 'public'""")
        for table in cursor.fetchall():
            print(table)
        myConnection.close()
if __name__=='__main__':
PostgreSQL()
```

There you have the notes table. You can't edit the notes, they are protected by the system of Pokertracker. cheers